# Automatically add component to app.module.ts?

Tags: angular

It seems like a basic feature to automatically add newly created components from the CLI into the `app.module.ts` yet we still have to go in every time after creating a component and add it in ourselves. Is there a flag that will automatically add it in for us?

Comment: What versions are you using? Components ARE automatically added to the relevant module - at least for all versions I’m using.

Answer (score 1):

By default it will automatically add your components on your module - but in case you need any help over it - `ng generate component [componentName] --module=app`

This command will work for your issue i think - hope it helps check this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component) for more commands

Happy coding :)

Comment: It adds the new component into the `declarations` of `app.module.ts` but I also need it under `entryComponents`. Is there a way to specify both objects?

Comment: Yeah you can add while creating your component but - your CLI version should be 7+ check commands over here https://angular.io/cli/generate#component

Answer (score 0):

What you need is documented quite well: https://angular.io/cli/generate#component

`ng g c -m app path/to/my.new.component` will generate a new component and add it to the main app module

`ng g c -m path/to/module path/to/my.new.component` will generate a new module and add it to a specific module

Works in Angular 7.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of angular cli is to put the generated components in app.module.ts. If you want to add it in any other module, you can set flag. Please read the documentation of angular-cli for more details. https://angular.io/cli/generate

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using an old version of @angular/cli because running generate component will automatically update the app.module.ts

[image]

Just update your npm @angular/cli package for your project and globaly:

Uninstall it first:

> npm un @angular/cli
>
> npm un @angular/cli -g

Then install it:

> npm i @angular/cli --save-dev
>
> npm i @angular/cli -g

Another thing, you can and *--module or -m* (alias) for *Allows specification of the declaring module.*

You can see it in [@angular/cli docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component).